# How can I read physics textbooks very fast? [open]

Tags: soft-question, education

Is there a method of speed reading that works for physics textbooks? Like in general how can you read physics very fast?

Thanks!

Comment: Dude, seriously?

Comment: If you are very very fast in mathematics ( differential  and integral calculus and functions) very fast in logical reasoning and very good in the language of the book .(eiditic memory also would be very helpful)

Comment: Thank you @annav!

Comment: The quickest way would be to not bother trying to read a textbook in the first place.  You're almost certain to understand as much physics after that as doing what you're suggesting.  An experienced physicist would read reasonably quickly, e.g. an undergraduate text read by a PhD, but they would not have to learn and understand difficult concepts as they'd already know those.

Comment: Thank you @StephenG-HelpUkraine!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't. If you read something that is new to you you have to go through all the math and details and think about the topic extensively. Ask questions to yourself, answer them properly. That's the only way to make sure you understand everything.
At some point in your studying process things will look more familiar to you and your reading speed will increase naturally. But until then you need to spend a lot of time. Not just months, but years.